# Run Scrapy spider multiple times programmatically without multiple processes or simultaneously

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a Scrapy spider that scrapes the content of a webpage and the webpages' item will be dependent on argument passed to the spider. `scrapy runspider myspider -a ID=1`

I've been trying to create a sort of "spider composer" by using CrawlerProcess and CrawlerRunner but the problem is that I can't run a spider multiple times sequentially because the reactor can't be restarted (`twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable`). The only way I manage do this is to run multiple instances of the same spider simultaneously but this gives me another error, `twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on 127.0.0.1:6073: [Errno 98] Address already in use`. Which makes sense since I'm trying to scrape too many webpages simultaneously.

Basically what I am trying to do:

```
for id in ids:
    process.crawl(MySpider, ID=id)
    process.start()
```

I've seen people suggesting using multiple processes for these kinds of things but since I am scraping up to a couple of million webpages in total then it's not really sustainable, and I also don't want to unintentionally DDOS their servers.

Comment: If you have all the IDs at the start, then compose the urls in the `start_requests` method and then tweak the value of `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` to change the scraping speed to the level you want. Scrapy is asynchronous and is capable of handling multiple concurrent requests out of the box. No need to restart the spider multiple times. However if you still need to do that check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079842/how-to-make-scrapy-spider-crawl-again-if-condition-is-not-met/71089095#71089095)

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for since I won't have all the ids at the start, my composer.py file is communicating with a database that gets more ids concurrently from another spider. Solved the issue by using multiprocessing, starting the spider in a separate process and then killing it when it's done scraping, but only running them one at a time

Comment: @blueberry73 that sounds interesting! Do you have a platform where you can share this scraper with the multiprocessing features? I would be very interested to learn how you did it for research purposes.